# Transpose two named ranges into same destinations cells with line break in between 1st and 2nd

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, line-breaks, named-ranges

YIn E2 my function **=IF($B2=3,TRANSPOSE(Opponent3STARS))** works perfectly for me
And in E7 my function **=IF($B7=2,TRANSPOSE(Opponent2STARS))** also works for this named range

However in E6, I'd like to be able to use both of those to basically get what appears in E2 directly on top of what appears in E7. And in that same order, and such that it only gets transposed into the same size destination range of E6:I6.

Can someone help me figure out the proper way to construct the function for that?

Thanks!

I tried to use **CHAR(10)**, **IFS**, **CONCENTATE**, etc., but I think I just missed what the correct format is.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=IF($B6=2.5,transpose(map(Opponent3STARS,Opponent2STARS,lambda(a,b,a&char(10)&b))))
```

[image]

**UPDATED FORMULA**

```
=index(if(B2:B21=3,torow(Opponent3STARS),
           if(B2:B21=2.5,torow(map(Opponent3STARS,Opponent2STARS,lambda(a,b,a&char(10)&b))),
           if(B2:B21=2,torow(Opponent2STARS),
           if(B2:B21=1.5,torow(map(Opponent2STARS,Opponent1STARS,lambda(a,b,a&char(10)&b))),
           if(B2:B21=1,torow(Opponent1STARS),
           if(B2:B21=0.5,torow(map(Opponent1STARS,Opponent0STARS,lambda(a,b,a&char(10)&b))),
           if(B2:B21=0,torow(Opponent0STARS)))))))))
```

- this is an arrayformula which extends automatically for the entire range `E3:E21`. you may need to clear the cells in the above said range of any existing formulas so that arrayformula is not blocked by them.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much!
Apologies, but would you be able to help me incorporate that into a larger function for all of those values in B and whether they hold true for each?
I tried combining yours and mine for $B3, but I'm getting errors when I try it.
(i.e, if $B3 = 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5, OR 0 and then expanding the function to the bottom row so it applies to all)

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: Yes @rockinfreakshow, apologies. See link for a copy. I;v hidden the other two worksheets that it may be referincing in parts:
[link(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13vBDWC2EFEwzVv1Om6xp2s2Cv0a85OVLACSlfUwAR94/edit?usp=sharing)
I was also going to do it for columns N-R and W-AA, but I figured it would be the same process as with the first, right?

Comment: you mean like a single formula to meet all the conditions (3,2.5,2,1.5...) instead of separate formulas for each condition?

Comment: Yes. I'd like each range row to be able to test for whether it meets each condition, find the one it does meet, and then apply the result of only that one. If that makes sense. And I was hoping that if I got it for one then I could just drag the function down to apply it to the others.

Comment: updated the formula in the answer. please do check it out.

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well google just straight up removed torow() and most of their other newly introduced functions for a couple of days ago. Apparently there are issues with them that they still needed to address lol.Hopefully that gets fixed so it can be restored soon.

Comment: within your case scenario, replacing `torow` with `transpose` should suffice.

Comment: That it does. Thanks once again!